# Google spreadsheet query function - including a range of data in the Where clause

Tags: sql, function, google-sheets

Lets say I have this query...

```
=query(DataSource!A1:C100,"select A, B, C where C = '123 or C = '456' order by C ",1)
```

I don't want to hard-code the 'Where' values in the statement because I would like to point to a range that contains an undetermined number of values.

Such as E1:E10, with the condition that sometimes the values in that range may be anywhere from 1 value (in E1) or 6 values (E1:E6) or 10 values (E1:E10).

Is it possible to write an alternative to 'Or' that would be the equivalent of...

```
...where C = """&E1:E10&""" order by C ",1)
```

(or a named range equivalent to that)

I've tried multiple ways of attaining this, but to no avail. I'm pretty much just throwing things against the wall at this point, but nothing sticks.

Can someone nudge me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just learned that it's possible to reference a cell on the spreadsheet that contains the "Select" statement itself. I'm now working on constructing a CONCAT function that will build that statement in that cell.

Comment: Easier said than done.

Comment: It looks like I've got the solution. I'm just going to play with it and see what more I can do with it. Then I'll post the results for others to see/use if they need something the same or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to make it so that this is not an unanswered question that people will continue to click on.

I do have my solution, but I'm in the middle of incorporating it into the overall scheme, so it's going to take me a while to come back here and post the solution.

In the meantime, no assistance needed. Thanks.

Comment: Anything on your solution?